# How's the damping factor in Google PageRank algorithm calculated

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm doing some researches about Google's PageRank algorithm for my thesis, I've found that the damping factor x (for example), where x is in :

> P` = x.P + (1-x)Q

where P is the original transition matrix

The damping factor x is set to be 0.85, why and how is that calculated ?

Comment: If it is too high, too litttle damping takes place; If it is too low, too much damping. It has to be just right for the purpose.

Comment: Thx for the comment, I know that in fact if x is too high the Q (which represents the user's taste transition matrix) is not taken in very consideration (and which is pretty much like you said), and vice versa, what I'm trying to look for is how is it mathematically found or proven. (it's just to try if I can change its value (0.85) for better results). thx again

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3090897/169085